# Notification: PendingIntent.getActivity how to refresh if activity is already open else open new activity

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying the following code for notification, so that it will refresh the activity if its already open else open a new activity. But i don't want it to open another activity when the activity is already open.

```
 Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Myplanshow.class);
 startIntent.putExtra("table_name", table_name);
 startIntent.putExtra("changed", changed);
 startIntent.putExtra("plannumber", plannumber);
 startIntent.putExtra("scrollposition", placeposition);
 startIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 101, startIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

it opens but the back button does not work. It think the currently running app is closed and only this activity is created.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the **launchMode** of your *Myplanshow.activity* as **singleTop** inside *AndroidManifest.xml* file of your application.

Working : If an instance of Myplanshow.activity is present at the top of the activity Task stack, the intent will be delivered to it in its **onNewIntent()** method rather than creating a new instance of the activity. This is the method where you can perform your operations. 
Else if no instance of the activity is present in the stack, it will create a new instance of the activity and pass the intent bundle.

Using the above method would not require you to add the activity flags - *NEW_TASK* and *CLEAR_TASK*.

Also do check out the official documentation before proceeding.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: what i found is its killing the app and then starts the Myplanshow activity. But when i click back, no app is visible which i have opened